# c1 TrueDBGrid cell value to textbox

Tags: c#, componentone, truedbgrid

```
private void c1TrueDBGrid1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


}
```

How can I get the value of a cell and then display it in a textbox. 
Just like this code that works for data grid view `"OwnerIDtxtbox.Text = PetGrid.Rows[i].Cells[7].Value.ToString();"`

Comment: I found the answer

int i = c1TrueDBGrid1.Row;
            

            try
            {
                txtbox_name.Text = c1TrueDBGrid1[i, 1].ToString();
                
              

                
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error Occurred while binding.");
            }

Comment: You've found the answer and posed it 41 minutes after I've written my answer, that contains exactly the same code. How lovely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`c1TrueDBGrid` exposes a couple of indexers that takes the row number as first parameter and the column name or index as the second - you can use either one of them.
Please note that both returns `object`.

```
var row = grid.Row; // get the current row

var columnIndex = 0;
var cellValue = grid[row, "ColumnName"];
var cellValue = grid[row, columnIndex];
```

Another option is to use

```
var value = grid.Columns[0].CellValue(row);
```

And of course, you can use the column's string indexer:

```
var value = grid.Columns["Company"].CellValue(row)
```

For more information, [please refer to official documentation.](http://help.grapecity.com/componentone/NetHelp/c1truedbgrid/webframe.html#C1.Win.C1TrueDBGrid.4~C1.Win.C1TrueDBGrid.C1TrueDBGrid_members.html)